# Using if or ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe in which I need to make a single observation in a column different based on the value of a variable in another column. I am new to programming and am having a difficult time finding a concrete example that I can follow. When the Item value is 1615, Epoch should be 261, and at all other levels of Item, Epoch should not change. The dataframe name is myevents. Here is an example of the data:

| Item | Epoch |
| --- | --- |
| 1612 | 260 |
| 1613 | 0 |
| 1614 | 0 |
| 1615 | 0 |
| 1616 | 0 |
| 1617 | 0 |
| 1618 | 262 |
| 1619 | 0 |

Here is what the output should look like:

| Item | Epoch |
| --- | --- |
| 1612 | 260 |
| 1613 | 0 |
| 1614 | 0 |
| 1615 | 261 |
| 1616 | 0 |
| 1617 | 0 |
| 1618 | 262 |
| 1619 | 0 |

Here is what I have tried:

```
myevents$Epoch=ifelse(myevents$Item==1615, myevents$Epoch==261, myevents$Epoch==myevents$Epoch)

myevents$Epoch=ifelse(myevents$Item==1615, myevents$Epoch==261, myevents$Epoch)

myevents$Epoch <- with(myevents, ifelse(myevents$Item==1615, myevents2$Epoch==261, myevents$Epoch==myevents$Epoch))

myevents$Epoch <- with(myevents, if(myevents$Item==1615, myevents$Epoch==261))
```

None of the above worked, and some actually replace the column with all `TRUE` or `FALSE` characters instead. I have made sure all numbers are being treated as numeric, and for good measure I did try wrapping them in single quotes just in case. I've also tried using forms if just `if` alone but I cannot figure out how to use it in a way that actually runs. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost working. the main confusion seems to come from the usage of `ifelse` (which you had the right intuition to use):

```
myevents$corrected <- ifelse(myevents$Item==1615, 261, myevents$Epoch)
```

Or, if you want to overwrite directly:

```
myevents$Epoch <- ifelse(myevents$Item==1615, 261, myevents$Epoch)
```

`ifelse` returns a value, that we assign to a variable, we don't assign in the ifelse statement itself. (or more precisely, `ifelse` returns either its second or third argument, depending on the outcome of the comparison in the first argument)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I figured I was just a  bit off.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do without if or ifelse would be this if I understood well your question:

```
myevents[myevents$Item %in% 1615,"Epoch"]= 261
```

Comment: This worked as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You already have several answers with the code for base R, so I left it out of my answer. You can certainly use some of the great base R answers you already have, but here are a couple of other options using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# random data to work with for the post
set.seed(3625)                 # set seed for the sample()
df <- data.frame(Item = sample(rep(1610:1620, times = 5)))
#    Item
# 1  1612
# 2  1611
# 3  1616
# 4  1616
# 5  1612
# 6  1620
# 7  1618
# 8  1619
# 9  1617
# 10 1615
#... 55 rows
    
df <- df %>%           # using ifelse
  mutate(Epoch = ifelse(test = Item == 1612,
                        yes = 260,
                        no = ifelse(test = Item == 1615,
                                    yes = 261,
                                    no = ifelse(test = Item == 1618,
                                                yes = 262,
                                                no = 0))))
#    Item Epoch
# 1  1612   260
# 2  1611     0
# 3  1616     0
# 4  1616     0
# 5  1612   260
# 6  1620     0
# 7  1618   262
# 8  1619     0
# 9  1617     0
# 10 1615   261 
#... 55 rows

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Epoch2 = case_when(      # alternative to ifelse
    Item == 1612 ~ 260,
    Item == 1615 ~ 261,
    Item == 1618 ~ 262,
    TRUE ~ 0))
#    Item Epoch Epoch2
# 1  1612   260    260
# 2  1611     0      0
# 3  1616     0      0
# 4  1616     0      0
# 5  1612   260    260
# 6  1620     0      0
# 7  1618   262    262
# 8  1619     0      0
# 9  1617     0      0
# 10 1615   261    261 
#... 55 rows
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you are trying to say, but what do you mean by *"when you called each vector independently (data$column) you were no longer linking the different rows."* The ordering in the dplyr version is depending on the same guarantee as the base R solution. After all, a data.frame is just a list of lists...  Also, I don't get the point of the nested `ifelse`...

Comment: @dario Ya, I misspoke. I'm going to edit my post and take that out, but I wanted to own up to it first. `ifelse()` does iterate. For some reason, I was thinking otherwise. As for the nested `ifelse()`, if you do it this way, you don't have to create a column first with arbitrary values, which you need to do with one-by-one settings. However, you should use what works best for you, of course. If you wanted to assign the values to a prepopulated column, there are a ton of ways to make that happen, as well.